# dynamic css using jquery width() and on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on(".wrapper-parallax", function(){
    var height = $(window).width() / 8; 

    $(this).css("margin-top",height);
}
```

this code seem doesn't run in 'real time', I want the result (margin-top's value) to change along I resizing the window.

Comment: I think you are trying  `var height = $(window).height() / 8;` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a window resize handler

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var height = $(window).width() / 8; //may be height() here instead of width()
    $(".wrapper-parallax").css("margin-top", height);
}).resize()
```

Comment: I've never seen like that: `$(window).resize(....).resize()` can you explain about it?

Comment: @C-link that is to call the resize handler on initialization so that when the page loads you will have the correct value set..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing trailing `px`

Try:

```
$(document).on(".wrapper-parallax", function(){
    var height = $(window).width() / 8; 
    $(this).css("margin-top",height+"px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var height = $(this).height() / 8; 

    $('.wrapper-parallax').css("margin-top", height + 'px');
}
```